# Why won't my javascript/canvas polygon fill?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

so I've created a program that will get a list of coordinates of the United States from a local webserver. A client can get these coordinates by making a simple GET request. I'm trying to fill the states individually, however this does not seem to be working. My code to fill these are as follows

```
ctx.fillStyle= "#f00";
//coords holds an array of JSON objects, which store an array of coordinates under the 'coords' tag. These coordinates are stored in an array, which holds [x,y].
for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++){
            obj = coords[i]['coords'];
//Begin the path
            ctx.beginPath();
            for (var j=0; j<obj.length; j++){
//Draw each point on the path
                if (j!=obj.length-1){
                    ctx.moveTo(obj[j][0],obj[j][1])
                    ctx.lineTo(obj[j+1][0],obj[j+1][1])
                }
            }
//Close the path
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
```

For some reason, this does not fill. It draws them with a black outline just fine, but the fill does not happen. I have thrown up the data on gist, and can be found here. https://gist.github.com/ollien/44119f42187ec21ae2c8

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you do a moveTo, you 'break' the curve. I suggest you use only moveTo in the first place, then only lineTo :

```
ctx.fillStyle= "#f00";
//coords holds an array of JSON objects, which store an array of coordinates under the 'coords' tag. These coordinates are stored in an array, which holds [x,y].
for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++){
     obj = coords[i]['coords'];
     drawObj(obj);
}
```

with drawObj defined as :

```
function drawObj(obj) {
         if (obj.length<2) return;
         ctx.beginPath();
         var currObj = obj[0];
         ctx.moveTo(currObj[0], currObj[1]);
         for (var j=1; j<obj.length; j++){
             currObj = =obj[j]
             ctx.lineTo(currObj[0],currObj[1])
         }
         ctx.closePath();
         ctx.fill();
         ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. The real words for 'you're breaking the curve' are : 'you create a new sub-path within the current path'. But whatever !